# Export multiple ravendb databases with RavenDB Smuggler in one go

Tags: database, export, ravendb

I am trying to create a cronjob that exports all my raven DB databases in one go. I know the following command exports one particular database

`Raven.Smuggler out http://localhost:8080/ C:/temp/backup.ravendump -- database=MyDatabase`

Is there a way to export all databases with one command, so that I don't have to repeat the command for each database I want to export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a little open source application to do this for me. You can find it [here](https://github.com/securancy/mass-smuggler).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no such feature.

Looking at the implementation of the smuggler calling the process for each database or with a "export-all" parameter there won't be any benefits from doing so (like getting a point in time snapshot of all databases at the exact same time).

There's also a bundle to achieve this: [Periodic export](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/bundles/periodic-export).

If you're using smuggler to get an export as a backup of the database, i would recomment to use Raven.Backup instead. Seems like it is much faster - especially for larger databases. See [here](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/administration/backup-and-restore) how this works.